# FACL commands in Linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions

FACL commands [ setfacl, getfacl...]; I have really used them in Solaris but I am facing some issues while using them in Linux.
Is this FACL utility really compatible with LINUX??

Answer (score 1):

Command line is similar, api is different.  What is your problem?

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_setfacl.htm

Answer (score 1):

It is compatible in that it achieves the same results; allowing more flexibility in allowing access to additional users and groups besides the standard owner and group attributes.  The `man setfacl` and `man getfacl` will give you the details, but pretty sure the only differences I remember was on Solaris the commands were `setacl` and `getacl`.